# Dynamic component render in Vue for v-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to load v-select (vuetify) component dynamically using a JSON object which contains different properties
I have multiple select components where options will be provided by an API, I want to load v-select component dynamically each time as this schema can be used for other components as well such as v-text-field

Problem is the genders array (other similar arrays as well such as departments and managers) will be provided by an API hence it needs to be dynamically loaded on to v-select component but using vm (View Modal) I can't do this.

I have tried using computed properties and methods to retrieve genders array, but no luck.

**Vue**

```
<component :is="schema.component" v-model="jsonData[schema.value]" v-bind="schema.props"  v-on="schema.on">
```

**Script**

```
<script>
import {
  VSelect
} from 'vuetify/lib';

export default {
  components: {
    VSelect
  },
  data() {
    const vm = this;
    return {
     genders:['Male', 'Female', 'Other'],
     jsonData:{},
     schema: {
          component: 'v-select',
          value: 'GENDER',
          props: {
            items: vm.genders
          },
          on: {
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `is prop` accepts the component instead of a string. So, instead of passing `'v-select'` to `is prop` try passing imported `VSelect` variable.

Comment: Yes I know but I've already registered VSelect component. And component is rendered fine, just that it doesn't fetch data items from gender array, which is a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `vm` is not what you expect. Use computed properties when you want to set value depending on another variable of the component.

```
data() {
  return {
    genders:['Male', 'Female', 'Other'],
    jsonData:{}
  }
},
computed: {
  schema () {
    return {
      component: 'v-select',
      value: 'GENDER',
      props: { items: this.genders },
      on: {}
    }
  }
}
```